BertTokenizer vocab_size remains unchanged after adding tokens
I am using HuggingFace BertTokenizer and adding some tokens to it. Here are the codes:
from transformers import BertTokenizer

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('fnlp/bart-base-chinese')
print(tokenizer)

which outputs:
BertTokenizer(name_or_path='fnlp/bart-base-chinese', vocab_size=51271, model_max_length=1000000000000000019884624838656, is_fast=False, padding_side='right', truncation_side='right', special_tokens={'bos_token': '[CLS]', 'eos_token': '[EOS]', 'unk_token': '[UNK]', 'sep_token': '[SEP]', 'pad_token': '[PAD]', 'cls_token': '[CLS]', 'mask_token': '[MASK]'}, clean_up_tokenization_spaces=True),  added_tokens_decoder={
    0: AddedToken("[PAD]", rstrip=False, lstrip=False, single_word=False, normalized=False, special=True),
    100: AddedToken("[UNK]", rstrip=False, lstrip=False, single_word=False, normalized=False, special=True),
    101: AddedToken("[CLS]", rstrip=False, lstrip=False, single_word=False, normalized=False, special=True),
    102: AddedToken("[SEP]", rstrip=False, lstrip=False, single_word=False, normalized=False, special=True),
    103: AddedToken("[MASK]", rstrip=False, lstrip=False, single_word=False, normalized=False, special=True),
    104: AddedToken("[EOS]", rstrip=False, lstrip=False, single_word=False, normalized=False, special=True),
}

The vocabulary size is 51271. I add a token using .add_tokens() function:
tokenizer.add_tokens(["new_token"])

and it returns the number of added tokens, which is 1. If I execute the above line one more time, it will return 0, proving the token is indeed added to the tokenizer.
But I print the tokenizer.vocab_size, which is still 51271, the same as before. However, the len(tokenizer) is 51272, added 1.
How do I update the number of vocab_size after adding the new tokens (and save as a new tokenizer)?

Here's the documentation for add_tokens function.

If the new tokens are not in the vocabulary, they are added to it with indices starting from length of the current vocabulary and and will be isolated before the tokenization algorithm is applied. Added tokens and tokens from the vocabulary of the tokenization algorithm are therefore not treated in the same way.

Hence, what you are seeing is the expected behaviour. Added tokens and tokens from the original vocabulary are deliberately isolated. From the documentation, to add a new token and use it with the model you will need to:

Call add_tokens(["new_token"]) to add the new tokens.
For the tokens to actually be usable with its model, you will need to resize the model's token embedding matrix, as it will now be a different size.

from transformers import (
    BertTokenizer,
    BartForConditionalGeneration,
    Text2TextGenerationPipeline,
)

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("fnlp/bart-base-chinese")
model = BartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("fnlp/bart-base-chinese")

tokenizer.add_tokens(["new_token"])
model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))

text2text_generator = Text2TextGenerationPipeline(model, tokenizer)  
text2text_generator("new_token[MASK]的首都", max_length=50, do_sample=False) # successful inference thanks to model resize

and to save tokenizer (you may want to save the model too)
# to load back in, call from_pretrained with the paths to the folders.
tokenizer.save_pretrained("./tokenizer_folder")
model.save_pretrained("./model_folder")

It is of my understanding that the new tokens are unlikely to provide much semantic meaning within the model. The resize_token_embeddings method will simply create a newly initialized vectors from the standard norm distribution I've found this relevant topic for you. Although the topic is for a different model architecture, it's still relevant because both models are derived from PreTrainedModel.
The only use case that I can see here is adding characters that the model hasn't seen before. I'd be surprised if the model cannot create a word from all the given subwords in its vocabulary.
